# How to add shift+click functionality to checkboxmodel for grid in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, selection, multi-select

today I am facing a problem with shift+click functionality problem in `extjs 4`.I want to do same functionality as it is in `gmail`. On clicking checkbox with shift+click row should get selected.I have grid panel with `checkbox - selModel`. And I want to add this functionality on clicking on checkbox only not on cellclick. I have checked `mode` and `multiSelect` config from `checkboxModel` and `grid panel`, but they are working for row selection only not on checkbox selection.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, Working solution with `ext js 4.2`

```
Ext.define('MyApp.override.CheckboxModelOverrides', {
override: 'Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', 

 onRowMouseDown : function(view, record, item, index, e) {
    var me = this;

    if (index !== -1) {

        if (!me.allowRightMouseSelection(e)) {
            return;
        }

        if (e.shiftKey && me.lastFocused) {
            me.selectRange(me.lastFocused, record, e.ctrlKey);
            me.processSelection(view, record, item, index, e);
        }

        if (!me.isSelected(record)) {
            me.mousedownAction = true;
            me.processSelection(view, record, item, index, e);
        } else {
            me.mousedownAction = false;
        }
    }

  }   
});
```